# INSERT by ANSI_QUOTES mode

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, quoting, medoo

I'm having a problem trying to do an `INSERT`, it's succeeding even though it shouldn't.

My table structure:
[image: table structure]

Note: *given1*, *given2* and *given3* are **required fields**.

In my application I execute the following method (https://github.com/catfan/Medoo):

```
$this->medoo->insert('teste', ['dado2' => 11, 'dado3' => 'teste']);
```

This should not be accepted because data2 is of type `SET`, and data3 is of type INTEGER`. Even so, the insertion succeeds. Moreover, data1 **is not passed as an argument**, even though it is a required field.

I checked the MySQL log and got the following entries:

```
SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;
INSERT INTO "teste" ("dado2", "dado3") VALUES ('11', 'teste');
```

Running this SQL manually in the database, I discovered that the problem is in using `ANSI_QUOTES`. The database **somehow accepts the insert**, and instead of issuing an error message it issues a warning:
[image: print screen of the return message]

I think that is need to modify the Medoo source code or report this problem to MySQL. I do not know what to do.

MySQL version is 5.7.14
I use the MySQL Workbench 6.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mySQL server is set in `STRICT` mode, it produces error when you try to insert values that do not fit into a column. By calling `SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;` this strict mode is most likely disabled.

You can try to contact the author of Medoo framework or rather use another framework or just `PDO` to access your database.

See [mysql docs on server modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) for more information.

Comment: Perfect friend!!! Thanks for the info.

I solved the problem by commenting on line 121 of Medoo.php ($commands [] = 'SET SQL_MODE = ANSI_QUOTES') and adding the ANSI_QUOTES mode directly to the MySQL configuration. The problem is with Medoo, it should not delete all modes to leave only ANSI_QUOTES, should keep the other modes and add ANSI_QUOTES.